# Parsing data with Pandas - how to output match as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, substitution

I've got a routine to read in a CSV file and spit out selected columns that match specific criteria:

CSV Input File looks like this

| Name | Role | Login |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Phil | Role A | Role B | 2024/01/01 |
| Bob | Role A | Role B | 2024/02/01 |
| Arthur | Role A | Role C | 2024/01/04 |
| Jane | Role B | Role C | 2024/01/31 |
| Mary | Role A | Role D | 2024/02/12 |
| Liz | Role B | Role F | 2024/02/21 |
| Phoebe | Role C | Role D | 2023/11/21 |
| Mike | Role E | 2024/02/15 |
| Rick | Role D | Role E | 2024/01/13 |
| Hilary | Role F | 2024/01/11 |

I have a block of code that matches based on a passed value:

```
# Define function to check if a value matches any of the filter values
def matches_filter(value):
    value_lower = value.lower()
    for filter_value in value_lower.split("|"):
        filter_value_lower = filter_value.lower()
        for fvals in fltr_values:
            if fvals.lower() in filter_value_lower:
                return fvals.lower()
    return None

# Apply filter
# filtered_df = df[df[fltr_field].apply(matches_filter)]
df[fltr_field + "_matched"] = df[fltr_field].apply(matches_filter)
```

Based on passing the values "Role B" and "Role D" I'd like to replace whatever is in the Role column with the result of the filter. The net resulting table should therefore look something like this:

| Name | Role | Login |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Phil | Role B | 2024/01/01 |
| Bob | Role B | 2024/01/01 |
| Jane | Role B | 2024/02/03 |
| Mary | Role D | 2024/02/02 |
| Liz | Role B | 2024/02/12 |
| Phoebe | Role D | 2024/02/21 |
| Rick | Role D | 2024/01/31 |

So far, the code will filter so I only get strings containing "Role B" or "Role D" but I'd like to replace the string found with the match criterion, rather than the list of roles. Can someone explain what I need to change here?

To further explain based on comments received so far:

- What is the content of `fltr_field`?

`fltr_field` contains the name of the column to filter on (in this case, I'm filtering on the column called `"Role"`.

- Can you clearly explain what you're trying to do here?

I wish to replace the contents of the Role column with the matched value.

- What is the nature of the `"Login"` column?

The `"Login"` column contains the last login date.

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to do here. Can you further explain?

Comment: What is the logic for determining `login` column?

Comment: what is `fltr_field`?

Comment: pretty clear since the update by OP. Posted a suggestion. "Login" is only payload column

Comment: Your code wants to create a new column, while your desired output does not contain one. This is still a little misleading... In my answer, I opted for reproducing the desired output.

Comment: safe pattern match version posted for your review

Answer (score 1):

With this input dataframe generator:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'Phil', 1: 'Bob', 2: 'Arthur', 3: 'Jane', 4: 'Mary', 5: 'Liz', 6: 'Phoebe', 7: 'Mike', 8: 'Rick', 9: 'Hilary'}, 
                   'Role': {0: 'Role A | Role B', 1: 'Role A | Role B', 2: 'Role A | Role C', 3: 'Role B | Role C', 4: 'Role A | Role D', 5: 'Role B | Role F', 6: 'Role C | Role D', 7: 'Role E', 8: 'Role D | Role E', 9: 'Role F'}, 
                   'Login': {0: '2024/01/01', 1: '2024/02/01', 2: '2024/01/04', 3: '2024/01/31', 4: '2024/02/12', 5: '2024/02/21', 6: '2023/11/21', 7: '2024/02/15', 8: '2024/01/13', 9: '2024/01/11'}})

     Name             Role       Login
0    Phil  Role A | Role B  2024/01/01
1     Bob  Role A | Role B  2024/02/01
2  Arthur  Role A | Role C  2024/01/04
3    Jane  Role B | Role C  2024/01/31
4    Mary  Role A | Role D  2024/02/12
5     Liz  Role B | Role F  2024/02/21
6  Phoebe  Role C | Role D  2023/11/21
7    Mike           Role E  2024/02/15
8    Rick  Role D | Role E  2024/01/13
9  Hilary           Role F  2024/01/11
```

A regex pattern extraction looks like your best option:

```
# Define search - insert any number of Role letters inside the brackets
role_pattern = "(Role\s[BD])"
# Generate filtered table
df.assign(Role = df['Role'].str.extract(pat=role_pattern)
 ).dropna(subset = ['Role'])

     Name    Role       Login
0    Phil  Role B  2024/01/01
1     Bob  Role B  2024/02/01
3    Jane  Role B  2024/01/31
4    Mary  Role D  2024/02/12
5     Liz  Role B  2024/02/21
6  Phoebe  Role D  2023/11/21
8    Rick  Role D  2024/01/13
```

I saw no need for the complexity of a dynamic column name (I mean your `df[fltr_field + "_matched"]`) since the final column in your desired output is called `"Role"` anyways.

---

**Update to match various roles as whole words**
With alternative input,

- filtering roles "Alpha" and "Role B",
- in presence of other roles such as "Role A", "Role AB", "Aphal", "Alpha A"*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'Phil', 1: 'Bob', 2: 'Arthur', 3: 'Jane', 4: 'Mary', 5: 'Liz', 6: 'Phoebe', 7: 'Mike', 8: 'Rick', 9: 'Hilary'}, 
                   'Role': {0: 'Role A | Role B', 1: 'Role A | Role B', 2: 'Role A | Role C', 3: 'Role B | Role C', 4: 'Role A | Role D', 5: 'Role BA | Role F', 6: 'Role C | Role D', 7: 'Aphal', 8: 'Alpha B | Role E', 9: 'Alpha'},
                   'Login': {0: '2024/01/01', 1: '2024/02/01', 2: '2024/01/04', 3: '2024/01/31', 4: '2024/02/12', 5: '2024/02/21', 6: '2023/11/21', 7: '2024/02/15', 8: '2024/01/13', 9: '2024/01/11'}}

     Name              Role       Login
0    Phil   Role A | Role B  2024/01/01
1     Bob   Role A | Role B  2024/02/01
2  Arthur   Role A | Role C  2024/01/04
3    Jane   Role B | Role C  2024/01/31
4    Mary   Role A | Role D  2024/02/12
5     Liz  Role BA | Role F  2024/02/21
6  Phoebe   Role C | Role D  2023/11/21
7    Mike             Aphal  2024/02/15
8    Rick  Alpha B | Role E  2024/01/13
9  Hilary             Alpha  2024/01/11

# simple variant for whole words - caution: will mistake a "Role BA" for a "Role B":
role_pattern = "(Alpha|Role B)"
df.assign(Role = df['Role'].str.extract(pat=role_pattern)
 ).dropna(subset = ['Role'])

# Safe variant for whole words that prevents this: (with lookahead assertion)
role_pattern = '(Alpha(?=($|\s|))|Role B(?=($|\s|)))'
df.assign(Role = df['Role'].str.extract(pat=role_pattern)[0]
 ).dropna(subset = ['Role'])

     Name    Role       Login
0    Phil  Role B  2024/01/01
1     Bob  Role B  2024/02/01
3    Jane  Role B  2024/01/31
9  Hilary   Alpha  2024/01/11
```

The "safe variant" with lookahead assertion will function as long as roles are entered with " | " in between. It makes sure the role name is followed by

- either the end of the string ("$"),
- or your vertical separator after a space ("\s|").

Similarly, we could not only "look ahead" but also "look back"; you see: regex complexity will have to catch-up with the diversity of expected "roles", but there is no need to make it more complex than it needs to be.

References

- [re — Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
- [End of line char ($) doesn't work inside square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316254/end-of-line-char-doesnt-work-inside-square-brackets)
- [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973436/12846804)
- [Regular Expression Conditional Lookahead/Lookback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1721420/12846804)

Comment: would this still work if instead of "Role A", "Role B" etc. they were (for example) "Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Delta", etc. and I wanted to return either of "Beta" or "Delta" ?

Comment: @MarcusWebb In that case I'm adapting your input data and the regular expression to match whole words